# What's the differences between miles programs

Tags: europe, loyalty-programs, miles-and-more

I wanted to book a flight and the flight engine ask me to provide my miles program number between multiple options.

[image]

What's the differences between them? What is best option?
(mostly I travel inside Europe with low cost and maybe I'll fly to america in the far future.. I live in the middle east)

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "best option"? Unfortunately "best" is a subjective word which makes this question quite hard to answer.

Comment: I know that my question is a little bit odd.. This is my second flight and I little bit confuse..My travel plan (inside europe and maybe to america) doesn't help...?

Comment: There is no way for someone to describe them all, there are too many airlines within Star Alliance (and you have SkyTeam and OneWorld as well).  You need to think about your travel needs now and future, look at which airlines serve your homeland, then start researching which will fulfill your needs best.

Comment: Each one of the options is a different airlines? I really not familiar with this.. and thanks for commenting BTW :) :)

Comment: Yes each name is a different airline, airlines tend to have only one frequent flyer program.

Comment: @Tom I just saw Aegean Airlines in both EuroBonus and Miles & More.. does it make sence...?

Comment: Most airlines are "partners" with other airline programs. So you can sign up for Thai Airline's frequent flyer program and credit miles earned flying on United.  But how many points you get varies, so you need to sit down and start looking at any that might be applicable to your location and travel habits.

Comment: @Tom - Just to let you know - You helped me a lot! Thank you very very much!! :)

Comment: @Tom - Ethupian airlines - the airline I book in - is a member in Star Alliance - What does it means? If I choose Miles & more this Star Alliance will be worthless?

Comment: Star Alliance is just what its name says, an alliance, a group of airlines banded together for marketing and operational benefits.  There are three global alliances, Star Alliance, SkyTeam and One World, each with different member airlines.  You can usually credit miles from one alliance member to another, but not always evenly.  You really need to research each potential airline frequent flyer program to discover the pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no one best option.** It really depends on many factors including where you fly, how often, plus what kind of rewards and benefits you prefer. Some programs make certain routes easier to get awards on, others give perks such as free checked bags, discounts, etc.

Given a list of choices, **you can only choose a program you are already enrolled in**. So, if you are not a member of any program, you cannot choose any at this time. Almost all programs belong to one airline but some airlines are partners, so you can fly one airline and get points for a partner program.

**It is possible to be enrolled in multiple programs**. In this case multiple choices will be valid. You can only choose one per booking, so in that case select the right one based on your current status with the program. If you have a program with miles close to expiring for example, selecting that one usually resets the expiration. Otherwise, you may be close to getting a certain reward with a program and you can choose that one.

Now most airlines will let you credit points (or miles or whatever their virtual currency is called) after a flight is booked. In this case, you complete your booking and then enroll with the program. Once you get your account number, you call the program and tell them you flown on a particular flight and they will *usually* award you the points a few weeks later. There is a deadline to do this, which varies, so try to make the call within a month or so.

Comment: For a beginning flyer (and likely non-frequent flyer) signing up for multiple programs is a bad idea, as you will never accumulate enough to get any benefit.  Better to pick one and plan all future bookings on that airline or its partners.

Comment: @Itai I can't just sign up before booking? and another question...אתה ישראלי..??

Comment: Yes you can sign up at anytime, now, before booking, after booking, at the airport, even on the airplane.  Some airlines even allow you credit for flights you flew before signing up (though this is usually only for flights a month or less prior to sign up)

Comment: @Tom Thanks..Ethupian airlines - the airline I book in - is a member in Star Alliance - What does it means? If I choose Miles & more this Star Alliance will be worthless?

Comment: @J.Doe Ethopian is a member of Star Alliance means that if you fly another airline in the alliance they can give you points in your Ethiopian account. Conversely, if you have an account with another Star Alliance member, you can give that account to get points for flying Ethiopian.

Comment: @Tom - Yes, this was one of my rookie mistakes a few years back but I'm trying to keep the answer relatively simple. For J.Doe: Start with one program, then add one per alliance. That will prevent points fragmentation.

Comment: @J.Doe - Yes, you can sign up before booking. You might even get the account number which is what  you need. It depends the program, sometimes they send you the number by mail, so even if you sign up, you won't have it for the booking. I have no idea what the rest of your question means.